# Saber se a data está entre duas colunas do MySQL - Banco?

Tags: mysql

Fiz o código abaixo e funciona, a verificação consta se a data está contida entre as duas colunas e retorna o resultado.:

```
SELECT * FROM  `ips_bloqueados` 
WHERE ip = '::1' AND '2015-04-18' BETWEEN date(inicio) AND date(fim)
```

Porém gostaria de implementar para Data e Hora, quero que retorne se a data e hora se está contida entre as duas colunas, porém não estou conseguindo, o código não retorna nenhum resultado, porém era para retornar:

```
SELECT * FROM  `ips_bloqueados` 
WHERE ip = '::1' AND '2015-04-18 14:10:00' BETWEEN date(inicio) AND date(fim)
```

**O código Acima Retorna 0 Registros Encontrados.**

**Porém veja a estrutura do banco de dados:**

```
id_bloqueio   ip             inicio                   fim 

    20      '::1'    '2015-04-19 14:02:42'    '2015-04-19 14:17:42'

    19      '::1'    '2015-04-18 14:02:27'    '2015-04-18 14:17:27'

    18      '::1'    '2015-04-18 14:02:19'    '2015-04-18 14:17:19'

    17      '::1'    '2015-04-18 14:01:47'    '2015-04-18 14:16:47'

    16      '::1'    '2015-04-18 14:01:46'    '2015-04-18 14:16:46'
```

Comment: Em vez do link para descarregar o banco seria melhor colocar, na pergunta, meia dúzia de linhas da tabela.

Comment: Sem problemas amaral, fiz a edição sugerida, agora pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 3):

Você está a usar a função [Date()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date.asp) que retorna a parte referente à data de um campo DateTime.

A primeira *query* funciona porque está a comparar `'2015-04-18'` com o resultado de `Date(inico)` e `Date(fim)` que retorna esse formato ou seja:

`Date('2015-04-18 14:17:27')` retorna `'2015-04-18'`.

Na segundo *query* a comparação é feita com `'2015-04-18 14:10:00'` portanto nada será encontrado.

Note que você está a comparar strings e não DateTime´s.

Altere a query para:

```
SELECT * FROM  `ips_bloqueados` 
WHERE ip = '::1' AND '2015-04-18 14:10:00' BETWEEN inicio AND fim
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu pesquisei e consegui resolver a questão acima da de duas formas:

Primeira Maneira:

```
SELECT * FROM `ips_bloqueados` WHERE ip = '::1' AND '2015-04-18 14:10:00' >= inicio and '2015-04-18 14:10:00' <= fim
```

Segunda Maneira - Na minha Opinião mais funcional:

```
SELECT * FROM ips_bloqueados WHERE ip = '::1' AND  '2015-04-18 14:10:00' BETWEEN inicio AND fim
```

Comment: Isso é o que eu tinha dito na minha resposta.

Comment: Sim, não me atentei... Sim Obrigado...